# Typo? "If $G$ is a group, $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, and $K\unlhd G$. Is $H\cap K \unlhd H$ just if $K \subset H$?"

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $G$ is a group, $H$  and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, and $K\unlhd G$. Is $H\cap K \unlhd H$ just if $K \subset H$?

I believe that my book may have a typo.

Given $x \in H\cap K$, then $x \in H$ and $x \in K$, so, $gxg^{-1} \in K \subset H$

Is this true even when $K \not \subset H$? If yes, I don't know how.

The book is "Abstract Algebra: A First Course" by Dan Saracino.

Comment: Since you are checking for normality in $H$, the $g$ will be taken in $H$. Then $gxg^{-1}$ is in $K$ because $K$ is normal, and in $H$ because all three factors are in $H$. So it should be "$K\cap H$" rather than "$K\subset H$". So that is indeed a typo.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I edited with book's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $H\cap K\trianglelefteq H$, with or without such inclusion. Let $h\in H$ and $x\in H\cap K$. Then $hxh^{-1}\in H$ as a product of three elements of $H$, and $hxh^{-1}\in K$ because $K\trianglelefteq G$. So $hxh^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

Comment: My mistake was to consider $gxg^{-1}$. I understand. Thank you very much.